# Eliminate $p$ from these 2 equations.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, computational-mathematics

$$
X \ = \ 2 
\left[
\dfrac
{h_1pv_1}
{(1-p^2v_1^2)^{1/2}}
+
\dfrac
{h_2pv_2}
{(1-p^2v_2^2)^{1/2}}
\right]
\\
T_2 \ = \ 2 
\left[
\dfrac
{h_1/v_1}
{(1-p^2v_1^2)^{1/2}}
+
\dfrac
{h_2/v_2}
{(1-p^2v_2^2)^{1/2}}
\right]
$$

The Objective here is to eliminate $p$ from both these equations.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Since this is a site that encourages learning, you will get much more help if you show us what you have already done. Could you edit your question with your thoughts and ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See below the first steps to start:

$$\left\{{\begin{align*}
pv_1^2T_2-X&=\dfrac
{h_2 p
\left(
\dfrac
{v_1^2-v_2^2}
{v_2}
\right)
}
{(1-p^2v_2)^{1/2}}
\\ \ \\
pv_2^2T_2-X&=\dfrac
{h_1 p
\left(
\dfrac
{v_2^2-v_1^2}
{v_1}
\right)
}
{(1-p^2v_1)^{1/2}}
\end{align*}}\right. \\ \ \ \\ \ \ \\
\dfrac
{pv_1^2T_2-X}
{pv_2^2T_2-X}
=
-\dfrac
{h_2v_1}
{h_1v_2}
\left(\dfrac
{1-p^2v_1}
{1-p^2v_2}
\right)^{1/2} \ \to \ p^2=\ldots?$$

Comment: I suggest that you elaborate on these steps. The OP is clearly having difficulties to do algebraic manipulations and he might need some explanation.

Comment: OK. I will wait for the OP's questions and see where exactly his difficulties are, in order to give specific help if necessary.